# Incomprehensible result of a comparison between a string and null value in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

Can anyone explain to me the behavior of a comparison between a string and a null value.

DataFrame:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
["text_1,","text_1"],
["text_1,","text_2"],
["text_1,",None]
]).toDF("col1", "col2")


df1 = df.withColumn("equal", F.when(F.col("col1") == F.col("col2"), "equal").otherwise("not equal")
   
+-------+-------+----------+
|col1   |col2   |equal     |
+-------+-------+----------+
|text_1 |text_1 |equal     |
|text_1 |text_2 |not equal |
|text_1 |null   |not equal |  <*
+-------+-------+----------+


df2 = df.withColumn("equal", F.when(F.col("col1") != F.col("col2"), "equal").otherwise("not equal")

+-------+-------+----------+
|col1   |col2   |equal     |
+-------+-------+----------+
|text_1 |text_1 |equal     |
|text_1 |text_2 |not equal |
|text_1 |null   |equal     |   <*
+-------+-------+----------+
```

The `is equal` comparison seems to go well but the `is not equal` goes wrong.

Can anyone explain this to me and how can I solve this without checking on `.isNotNull` or fill the `null` values with an empty string (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you got `equal` for comparison with null is because `text1 != null` gives null, which is interpreted as false by the `when` statement, so you got the unexpected `equal` from the `otherwise` statement.

You can use `eqNullSafe`, which returns False instead of null when one of the column is null. If you want to compare inequality, use the negation `~` of `eqNullSafe`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df3 = df.withColumn("equal",
    F.when(~F.col("col1").eqNullSafe(F.col("col2")), "not equal")
     .otherwise("equal")
)

df3.show()
+------+------+---------+
|  col1|  col2|    equal|
+------+------+---------+
|text_1|text_1|    equal|
|text_1|text_2|not equal|
|text_1|  null|not equal|
+------+------+---------+
```

If you want to fill the null values with an empty string, you can use `coalesce`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df4 = df.withColumn("equal",
    F.when(F.col("col1") != F.coalesce(F.col("col2"), F.lit("")), "not equal")
     .otherwise("equal")
)

df4.show()
+------+------+---------+
|  col1|  col2|    equal|
+------+------+---------+
|text_1|text_1|    equal|
|text_1|text_2|not equal|
|text_1|  null|not equal|
+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is not a value but represents the lack of value. You can't compare it to a value nor to another null, the comparison always interpreted as false in `if`, `when` functions. For null safe equality check, you can also use SQL expression [`is distinct from`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/isdistinct.html):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "equal",
    F.when(
        F.expr("col1 is distinct from col2"), "not equal"
    ).otherwise("equal")
)

df1.show()

# +------+------+---------+
# |  col1|  col2|    equal|
# +------+------+---------+
# |text_1|text_1|    equal|
# |text_1|text_2|not equal|
# |text_1|  null|not equal|
# +------+------+---------+
```

Or using [`<=>`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_10) operator:

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "equal",
    F.when(
        F.expr("col1 <=> col2"), "equal"
    ).otherwise("not equal")
)
```